# Json.NET not properly deserializing System.Range property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class with a property as type `System.Range`. When I serialize the class to JSON the values are there and look correct. However, when I deserialize the JSON back into an object the Range is set to 0..0 and not the saved value.

Here is a simple example

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var room = new Room() {
            Name = "Hall",
            Capacity = 100..150
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(room);
        json.Dump();
    
        Console.WriteLine();
        var deRoom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room>(json);
        deRoom.Dump();
    }
}

public class Room {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Range Capacity {get;set;}
}
```

This dumps the following:

```
{"Name":"Hall","Capacity":{"Start":{"Value":100,"IsFromEnd":false},"End":"Value":150,"IsFromEnd":false}}}

Dumping object(Room)
 Capacity  : 0..0
 Name      : Hall
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jfOBNm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that properties of `Range` are readonly. You can validate it adding tracewriter:

```
MemoryTraceWriter traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
var deRoom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    TraceWriter = traceWriter,
});
// will output bunch of "Info Unable to deserialize value to non-writable property 'Value' on System.Index. Path 'Capacity.Start.Value', line 1, position 47."
Console.WriteLine(traceWriter.ToString());
```

You can implement your own `JsonConverter` to handle it. For example:

```
class RangeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Range));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObj = JObject.Load(reader);

        int value = 0;
        bool isFromEnd = false;

        var startObject = jObj.GetValue("start", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (startObject != null) {
            value = GetIntValue(startObject, "value");
            isFromEnd = GetBoolValue(startObject, "isFromEnd");
        }
        var startIndex = new Index(value, isFromEnd);

        var endObject = jObj.GetValue("end", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (endObject == null) {
            value = 0;
            isFromEnd = true;
        } else {
            value = GetIntValue(endObject, "value");
            isFromEnd = GetBoolValue(endObject, "isFromEnd");
        }           
        var endIndex = new Index(value, isFromEnd);

        return new Range(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

    private int GetIntValue(JToken token, string propertyName) {
        var intValue = ((JObject)token).GetValue(propertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        return intValue == null ? 0 : intValue.Value<int>();
    }

    private bool GetBoolValue(JToken token, string propertyName) {
        var boolValue = ((JObject)token).GetValue(propertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        return boolValue != null && boolValue.Value<bool>();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var deRoom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Converters = { new RangeConverter() } // add RangeConverter
});
deRoom.Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks seems to run fine in dotfiddle but when I modify the code I was testing in LinqPad I get the following error     at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(Object value, String parameterName)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value[T,U](IEnumerable`1 value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value[U](IEnumerable`1 value)
   at UserQuery.RangeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in

Comment: Seems like when "IsFromEnd' is missing (aka null) Value is throwing an exception

Comment: @BradPatton runs ok in my LinqPad. Yes, this was example code to provide the idea, the actual `ReadJson` should be improved(for example the index creation can be extracted to func). Also check json which you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the code. Testing it in my code I'm definitely getting some exceptions thrown. I will add some error checking and may update your answer.

Comment: There were issues with case sensitivity and when the start/end were missing. I've created a bunch of test cases and edited the code to hopefully handle all of the scenarios. Thanks for the help